# automated spatial Query QGIS

Tags: qgis, spatial-query

I'm using QGIS 2.18.3 (Las Palmas).
In order to determine the number of buildings within a district I'm using spatial Query in QGIS. I filter out the specific district within my city-layer so I can apply the spatial query to it. I then go into the attribute Table of my building-layer and input the district for the labelled buildings.

Is there a possibility to automate this process? Does spatial query have a batch-possibility?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are describing here is a "spatial-join", but you are doing it the hard way (using a spatial-query and doing the input manually).

You can find the proper Tool within Vector --> Data Management Tools --> Join attributes by location.
This tool will do the job for every building and district, no selection needed.

Answer (score 1):

You can use virtual field in qgis calculator or  Autofield plugin using conditional request(CASE WHEN... THEN...)  to choose the features to do spatial query